# Redux transition to after action execution

Tags: javascript, react-router, redux

I have an action like

```
export function loginSuccess(response){
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ response, type: types.LOGIN });
    router.transitionTo("/profile")

  };
}
```

Here after successful execution of my action I would like to redirect it to `/profile`.

Here I am getting `router is not defined`.

Comment: `router` should be passed in on `this.props`.

Comment: It is in my action .. how can I pass it in this.props..

Comment: Ah, didn't read carefully enough.  Are you using `redux-router`?

Comment: yes I am using it.. there I want to redirect it.. I saw it is the proper way but my router is not defined

Comment: If you use `redux-router`, then import `pushState` and dispatch.

Comment: can I use location.pathname = "/profile" .. its working for me.. ?? where should I do dispatch after importing pushState ?

Comment: the only problem I see is it is reloading the page..

Comment: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/advanced/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md can help

Comment: Maybe you can use pure javascript to force the transition using something like       window.location.assign("/profile");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass router to your redux thunk action creator (you pice of code is not an action but as I wrote action creator). For example it could looks like:

```
export function loginSuccess(router, response){
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ response, type: types.LOGIN });
    router.transitionTo("/profile")

  };
}
```

Do you have access to your router in place where you invoke this action creator ? is it available there? if yes then you have there something like this (I don't know what is `response`):

```
this.props.dispatch(loginSuccess(response));
```

and you have to change it to:

```
this.props.dispatch(loginSuccess(this.context.router, response));
```

I assume that you have access to router by context.

Because you don't show how you invoke this action I'm only guessing. I hope that my instruction will help you.

And one more thing. New react-router api don't have transitionTo method in router! I don't know if you use new or old api. But if you get error like:

> Calling `transitionTo` fails with: 'location.search.substring is not a function'

then change also :

```
router.transitionTo("/profile")
```

to:

```
router.push("/profile")
```

Comment: the thing is I am calling this action from my component and I am not getting `this` object is the action.. can you help...

Comment: Yes, write your component content in your question (if it is possible remove all obsolete code).

Comment: But if I have to guessing more. Then you tried to invoke your action in method which is invoking as callback. You can try to add in constructor:
`this.yourMethodWhichInvokeAction = this.yourMethodWhichInvokeAction.bind(this)`

Answer (score 1):

Outside components you can use [history](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md) to provide the current route

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

export function loginSuccess(response){
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ response, type: types.LOGIN });
    browserHistory.push("/profile")
  };
}
```

Comment: It gives result accordint to history of browser.. I dont want this... It would be so nice if you could explain how can I do this in redux way like router.transitionTo("/profile")